# Loop to add numbers in a range

Tags: java, loops, sum, int

I need help on how I can get the sum of both integers `start` and `finish` and store it into the `total` variable.
For example:

```
input: -10 -8
output: -27
reason: -10 + -9 + -8.
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] startFinish = scanner.nextLine().trim().split(" ");

        int start = Integer.parseInt(startFinish[0]);

        int finish = Integer.parseInt(startFinish[1]);



        System.out.println(total);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your range goes from smaller to greater, you can do, for example:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
    total += i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answers my question!